# Can't Return and Assign Variable from Function?

Tags: python, function, variables

Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm trying to write a function that will scramble a word and also remove any whitespace and return both the word lengh and word scrambled via a return. Also I'd like to be able to assign variables by simply calling the function and not just have it print out from the function. but it also doesn't even count and return the lengh of the number let alone store the variable from the function. I'm sure it's easy answer but I can't figure it out, code is messy in terms of variables because I keep trying another solutions

```
import random
import os

def scrambleWord (word_to_scramble, number_of_letters):
        number_of_letters = len(word_to_scramble)
        number_of_letters = len(word_to_scramble) - word_to_scramble.count(" ") # Assign lengh of word minus whitespace to variable
        return word_to_scramble
        return number_of_letters

user_word = input("Enter word\t")
user_count = 0
user_word_scrambled = ""
scrambleWord(user_word_scrambled, user_count)
print("Word to scramble is {0}, and is {1} letters long.".format(user_word, user_count))
```

Comment: when you return from a function the code after the return won't be execute. so `return number_of_letters` do nothing

Answer (score 0):

you have two return calls inside scrambleWord, if your trying to return two variables from a function you can use a Tuple for example:

```
def scrambleWord (word_to_scramble):
    number_of_letters = len(word_to_scramble) - word_to_scramble.count(" ")
    scramble_word=scramble(word_to_scramble)
    return (scramble_word,number_of_letters)
```

and then in main:

```
user_word = input("Enter word\t")
scrambled_word,user_count=scrambleWord(user_word)
**print the output
```

for scrambling words you can use the random package: `import random`

```
def scramble(word):
    word = list(word)
    random.shuffle(word)
    return ''.join(word)
```

I suggest reading more about function variables and how are they passed and returned from functions , you seem to be mixing up between passing by reference and value.

Comment: you don't need to use tuple for the return value.

you can just wright `return a, b, c ...`

Comment: that's also true, meaning you can ignore the parentheses but never the less the type of the value returned is a tuple

Comment: of course but it is considered as a bad practice to wrap the return value with parentheses

Comment: ohh didn't know that thank you, can you elaborate as to why? I'm really interested

Comment: Thank you everyone but this confuses me, the line
scrambled_word ,user_count = scrambleWord(user_input)
The function scrambled_word takes one arg and return two. So when declaring/passing the variables into the function and add the (user_input) because there is no second argument I wouldve thought it would be a error. Sorry if I'm  a bit slow with it trying to understand how functions work a bit and get better in general

Comment: a function is only a block of code that receives data(arguments) and returns a result, there can be only one  `return` inside a function and that is the result that's returned , one way to return more than one "result" is using tuples, there is no correlation between the two things(arguments that are passed to the functions and the return value) , I suggest reading more about functions in general and how do they operate [python functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To me , Write your code easily instead of hard Algorithm . You can count word count out of function and you just have a function for your business .
Anyway your answer is Like this :

```
def scrambleWord (word_to_scramble, number_of_letters):
        number_of_letters = len(word_to_scramble)
        number_of_letters = len(word_to_scramble) - word_to_scramble.count(" ") # Assign lengh of word minus whitespace to variable
        return number_of_letters,word_to_scramble
```